# "cc" opcode in debugger

Tags: debugging, opcode

can you explain what will happen if opcode "cc" or \xcc is in running debugger (i.e : windbg, immunity debugger, etc) ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. 
i've take some read about them, these opcode will cause making breakpoint in debugger. 
some program takes this opcode for anti-debugging implementations.